# Почему, если теги добавлены с помощью ajax, я не могу их прочитать с помощью JavaScript

Tags: javascript, ajax

Я искал это решение везде, но не смог найти ответ, который мог бы мне помочь. Мои теги отображаются с помощью ajax из базы данных таким образом, Код:

```js
function all() {
    // Ajax config
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET", //we are using GET method to get all record from the server
        url: 'all.php', // get the route value
        success: function (response) {//once the request successfully process to the server side it will return result here
            
            // Parse the json result
            response = JSON.parse(response);

            var html = "";
            // Check if there is available records
            if(response.length) {
                html += '<div class="list-group">';
                // Loop the parsed JSON
                $.each(response, function(key,value) {
                    // Our employee list template
                    html += '<a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action">'; 
                    html += "<p class='m-0'>" + value.let_txt_3 + "</p>";
                    html += "<p class='m-0'>" + value.let_txt_4 + "</p>";
                    html += "<p class='m-0'>" + value.let_txt_5 + "</p>";  
                    html += "<p class='m-0'>" + value.let_txt_6 + "</p>";  
                    html += "<button type='button' class='btn btn-primary' data-bs-toggle='modal' data-bs-target='#edit-employee-modal' id='edit_employee_modal' data-bs-id='"+value.id+"'>Edit</button>";
                    html += '</a>';
                });
                html += '</div>';
            } else {
                html += '<div class="alert alert-warning">';
                  html += 'No records found!';
                html += '</div>';
            }

            

            // Insert the HTML Template and display all employee records
            $("#employees-list").html(html);
        }
    });
}
```

Я хочу манипулировать html кнопкой но у меня не получается.

```
html += "<button type='button' class='btn btn-primary' data-bs-toggle='modal' data-bs-target='#edit-employee-modal' id='edit_employee_modal' data-bs-id='"+value.id+"'>Edit</button>";
```

Как пример помогите мне сделать следующее:

- При нажатие на кнопку чтобы выводился `alert("test");`
- Или `edit_employee_modal.style.color = "red";`

Моя проблема в том что я не знаю эту ошибку, `inspect` -> `console` (при нажатии на кнопку):

```
modal.js:332 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'classList')
at De._isAnimated (modal.js:332:26)
at De._initializeBackDrop (modal.js:205:24)
at new De (modal.js:82:27)
at De.getOrCreateInstance (base-component.js:55:41)
at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (modal.js:434:22)
at HTMLDocument.n (event-handler.js:120:21)
```

Что я пробовал?!

```
let edit_employee_modal = document.querySelector("#edit_employee_modal");
edit_employee_modal.onclick = function() {
    edit_employee_modal.style.color = "red"; 
}
```

Пробовал выполнить скрипт после загрузки страницы:

```
window.document.onload = function(e){ 
let edit_employee_modal = document.querySelector("#edit_employee_modal");
    edit_employee_modal.onclick = function() {
        edit_employee_modal.style.color = "red"; 
    }
}
```

И заменял на код ниже, тоже не получилось (Потому что я думаю, что javascript не может прочитать мои теги):

```
window.onload = function(e){ 
   //code 
}
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) { 
  // code 
});
```

Можете ли вы помочь мне с любыми идеями?

ps: я новичок не судите строго

Comment: Дело в том что все ваши попытки обратиться к нужной кнопке были после того как DOM был распарсен и до того как кнопка (или любые другие элементы) была вставлена после запроса. Чтобы не париться на счёт того, когда же к кнопке можно обратиться, предлагаю вам с самого начала вставить в вашу вёрстку кнопку (или любые другие элементы), но скрыть, а когда придёт ответ от сервера, от достать эту кнопку (или любые другие элементы) вставить туда ваш текст и слушатель и только после этого их показать

Comment: Есть и второй способ, вы можете создать всё что вам нужно после ответа сервера, через `document.createElement`, тогда вы так же сможете вставить любой текст, навесить нужные обработчики событий и в конце все эти элементы вставить в ваш HTML

Comment: @eziomercer Первый вариант понравился, не подумал, попробую, спасибо 

Comment: Обратите внимание, что у всех кнопок одинаковый id

Comment: Ну это не значит что скрипт не должен работать, хоть для первой но должен

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не важно каким способом мы получили данные, важно обратиться к элементам (кнопкам) после того, как они добавлены в DOM.

Есть простой дедовский способ, когда мы явно задаем атрибут `onclick` в подгружаемых данных:

```js
function addButton() {
  buttons.innerHTML += '<button type="button" class="btn-edit" onclick="eventHandler(this)">Edit</button>';
}

function eventHandler(e) {
  e.style.background = 'red';
}
```

```html
<div id="buttons"></div>
<button onclick="addButton()">Добавить</button>
```

Если хотите назначить обработчики после добавления HTML, то так и делаете:

```js
function addButton() {
  buttons.innerHTML += '<button type="button" class="btn-edit">Edit</button>';
  attachEvents();
}

function attachEvents() {
  let buttons = document.querySelectorAll('.btn-edit');

  for (let btn of buttons) {
    btn.addEventListener('click', eventHandler);
  }
}

function eventHandler(e) {
  this.style.background = 'red';
}
```

```html
<div id="buttons"></div>
<button onclick="addButton()">Добавить</button>
```

В вашем случае, добавить обработчики нужно после `$("#employees-list").html(html)`, ведь метод html() не является асинхронным.

Comment: Спасибо, это сработало