# Как обработать событие в элементах полученных через AJAX?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Я только начинаю изучать работу AJAX запросов и PHP, многого могу не знать, могу что-то упустить.

Есть страница index.php, на ней с помощью AJAX выводится список вакансий в виде карточек, а также пагинация.

Страница index.php

```
<body>
<section class="mt-3 content">
    <div class="container">
        <h2>Стажировки</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="container" id="target-content">
        <div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
            <div class="spinner-grow" style="width: 3rem; height: 3rem;" role="status">
                <span class="visually-hidden">Загрузка...</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <nav class="mt-4" aria-label="Page navigation example">
        <ul class="pagination justify-content-center">
            <?php
            if (!empty($total_pages)) {
                for ($i = 1; $i <= $total_pages; $i++) {
                    if ($i == 1) {
            ?>
                        <li class="page-item active" id="<?php echo $i; ?>"><a href="#target" data-id="<?php echo $i; ?>" class="page-link"><?php echo $i; ?></a></li>
                    <?php
                    } else {
                    ?>
                        <li class="page-item" id="<?php echo $i; ?>"><a href="#target" class="page-link" data-id="<?php echo $i; ?>"><?php echo $i; ?></a></li>
            <?php
                    }
                }
            }
            ?>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</section>
</body>
```

Есть AJAX запрос к странице, откуда выводятся записи:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
    $("#target-content").load("index-handler.php?page=1");
    $(".page-link").click(function () {

        var id = $(this).attr("data-id");
        var select_id = $(this).parent().attr("id");
        $.ajax({
            url: "index-handler.php",
            type: "GET",
            data: {
                page: id
            },
            cache: false,
            success: function (dataResult) {
                $("#target-content").html(dataResult);
                $(".page-item").removeClass("active");
                $("#" + select_id).addClass("active");
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Есть страница откуда выводятся записи, index-handler.php:

```
<?php
include('database.php');
$limit = 20;
if (isset($_GET["page"])) {
    $page_number  = $_GET["page"];
} else {
    $page_number = 1;
};
$initial_page = ($page_number - 1) * $limit;
$sql = "SELECT v.id as vacancy_id, v.name as vacancy_name, v.salary, v.description, emp.city, emp.name as emloyer_name FROM vacancies v LEFT JOIN employers emp ON v.employer_id = emp.id ORDER BY v.id DESC LIMIT $initial_page, $limit";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
?>
    <div class="card w-100 mb-2">
        <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title"><?php echo $row["vacancy_name"]; ?></h5>
            <p class="card-text text-primary"><?php echo $row["salary"]; ?></p>
            <p class="card-text"><?php echo $row["description"]; ?></p>
            <p class="card-text"><?php echo $row["city"]; ?></p>
            <p class="card-text text-muted"><?php echo $row["emloyer_name"]; ?></p>
            <a class="btn btn-primary feedback-btn" data-req="<?php echo $row["vacancy_id"];?>">Откликнуться</a>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php
};
?>
```

Кнопка в карточке, полученная из index-handler.php имеет класс feedback-btn, я хочу, чтобы при нажатии на кнопки с этим классом срабатывал обработчик событий, который касается только той кнопки, на которую нажали (через новый ajax запрос отправить id карточки и внести его в базу данных). Однако перед тем как отправить запрос, нужно навесить на эти кнопки обработчик событий, чтобы изменить содержимое кнопки на что-то вроде "Загрузка...", и уже после того как отработает ajax запрос, содержимое через success изменится на какое-то по умолчанию.

Я столкнулся с такой проблемой - те карточки с кнопками, которые я получил не обрабатывают клики.
Например такой простой код не срабатывает:

```
var elements = document.querySelectorAll(".feedback-btn");
for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
  elements[i].onclick = function() {
    alert("Клик");
  };
}
```

Его я добавлял в конец главной страницы index.php, однако подобный код вполне корректно работал для кнопок, которые итак статически были прописаны на странице index.php.

Я не понимаю, как сделать обработку событий для этих кнопок в карточках, полученных через ajax.

К примеру: Данные карточки я получил с index-handler.php по ajax, при нажатии на кнопки в них ничего не срабатывает.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Есть и такие кнопки, c тем же классом feedback-btn, они прописаны в самом index.php, но при нажатии на них всё срабатывает

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Совсем недавно был [аналогичный вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1415860/443096)

Answer (score 0):

Пока я двигаюсь в сторону делегирования. Добавил на страницу index.php такой код:

```
const box = document.querySelector("#target-content");
box.addEventListener("click", function(e){
  let targetItem = e.target;
  if (targetItem.closest(".feedback-btn")){
    targetItem.innerHTML = "Нажата!"
  }
})
```

Обратился к блоку, в который грузятся карточки и впрочем могу так что-то обрабатывать.